# Full adder carry expression

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits, combinatory-logic

I'm learning about logic circuits and I've come across full adder. In the book they  derived its two carry out expressions -

Cout = x&&y || x&&z || y&&z 
and 
Cout = x&&y || (x'&&y || x&&y')&&z

I've tried to get the second equation from the first one but couldn't. Any one knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is unclear what $x$, $y$ and $z$ are. However, the two formulas are equivalent. Let me use products to denote a logical "AND" and additions to denote a logical "OR" so that your first formula becomes $xy + xz  + yz$

If you gather $z$ in the last two terms you get:
$xy + (x+y)z$.

Notice how the second term $(x+y)z$ is true iff $z$ is true, and at least one of $x$ and $y$ is true. However, if both $x$ and $y$ are true, the whole formula is true regardless of the truth value of the second term (since the first term is $xy$).
You can then replace $(x+y)$ with $(x \oplus x)$ (where "$\oplus$" denotes the exclusive OR) to obtain:
$xy + (x \oplus y)z$ or, equivalently, $xy + (x'y + xy')z$.

Comment: But how this characteristics that, if both x and y is 1 the total output is 1 independent of z and if one of x or y is 1 and z is 1 then total output is 1, can change the or operation to xor?

Comment: Start from $xy + (x+y)z$. We now change the second OR to a XOR. If at most one of $x$ and $y$ is true then $x \oplus y$ is equivalent to $x+y$. If both $x$ and $y$ are true, then the first term is true, and hence both the original and the modified formulas are true.

Comment: Hmmmm understood. Previously I was thinking they used some kind of simplification to derive the second formula. Thanks.